# Masking an URL after redirect

Tags: redirect, http-redirect

We are building a SaaS solution which runs on SaaS.com for example. Our software should be white label for our resellers and their costumers. The costumers of our resellers are stored in an specific database witch is different for each reseller.

The reseller creates a button on his website [Login] which sends the customer resellerID.my.saas.com Our software gets the resellerID and selects the corresponding branding and database. This all works fine in an development environment at the moment.

We have only 1 thing which we need to solve and that is the url what the customer of the reseller sees in his browser. This is (after logging in) my.saas.com

We want that the customer of the reseller sees the domain of the reseller after they are redirected to our link (resellerid.my.saas.com), for example my.reseller.com

I googled a lot and asked our and 3th party developers how to solve this. Till now the only solution we found is using an iframe which has not our preference. This becouse this is not optimal for mobile views? and is out dated, isn't it? 
I also tried to solve this with dns which i couldn't get done.

Is there any way to achieve what we want and when yes, how can we implement?

Hope on usefull responds becouse this part is verry crusial for our business.

Thanks in advance, Rogé

Comment: Sounds like you want a reverse proxy.

Comment: Thanks, looks this can be the solution. I fly in vacation for about 8 days now, when i'm back i will learn more about reverse proxies.